# Products between metrics in a product of manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, terminology, notation

In the "Einstein Manifold" book written by Arthur Besse, chapter 16, there is a notation of a manifold composed by the Cartesian product between two others:

$(M_1\times M_2, f^p(g_1 \times g_2))$

Where $g_i$ is the metric of the $M_i$ manifold. Here $f^p(g_1 \times g_2)$ is the metric of the manifold $M_1 \times M_2$ and $f$ is a determined function and $p$ a parameter.

I think that the function $f^p$  is only multiplying the product between metrics and depends on all coordinates of manifold, but I don't know what is the meaning of $g_1 \times g_2$. Is this a warped product or not? Because in another part appears $f(g_1 \oplus g_2)$, and I understand that the $\oplus$ is the sum of the  metrics. I mean, if $g_1=g_t dt^2+g_x dx^2$ and $g_2=g_y dy^2+g_z dz^2$, then $g_1 \oplus g_2=g_t dt^2+g_x dx^2+g_y dy^2+g_z dz^2$, but what about $g_1 \times g_2$?

Comment: In the introduction to that chapter, the notation $(M_1 \times M_2, f^p (g_1 \times g_2))$ appears where $g_1 \times g_2$ is the Riemannian product of the metrics and $f : M_1 \to (0,\infty)$ obeys a Helmholtz-type equation.  So it is conformal to the riemannian product.  You can think of it as a warped product, if you wish, but not of $g_1$ and $g_2$.  The notation $g_1 \times g_2$ and $g_1 \oplus g_2$ are synonymous, I think.

Comment: The next equation (equation 16.13 in my version) represents a special case of the given metric and it is clear that the author means by $g_1\times g_2$ the sum of the metrics as I understand. Kindly notice that it is not a warped product since the function $f$ is defined on the product not on the base only. The given case is a conformal change of the direct product metric while the metric in 16.13 is a warped product metric.

Comment: One more thing. The first time $g_1\times g_2$ appears is in 10.33 and the author defined it as in 1.37. In 1.37 the metric is just a sum of $g_1$ and $g_2$. I hope it helps out.